# IntielliJ is using folder "${project.build.directory}" instead of "target" as maven build/run target

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea

I want intellij to go back to using `target`.

On 2022-10-24 a new folder appeared in my project that was literally named
`${project.build.directory}`.  I was busy so I ignored and `.gitgignore`d this for awhile but I finally found time to examine it today. It turns out, Intellij is now using this to store and run class files, and the class files in `target` are out of date.

1. When I run mvn compile, the `.class` files are deposited in `target`.
2. When I run build or test in IntelliJ, the the `.class` files are created in the folder named `${project.build.directory}'.
3. Anything in my `target/generated-sources` folder is copied into the folder named `${project.build.directory}/classes`.

I did a check on `pom.xml` and it has not been changed since May.

I compared `.idea/compiler.xml` with a pre-October version of the file and there have been no changes.

I am running Java 17.0.1 installed by homebrew in 10-2021, Maven 3.8.4, and IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.4 Ultimate edition which was reportedly built 2021-12-21. I was running a September install of MacOS 12.6 on October 24 and have since upgraded to 13.0. The IntelliJ Maven plugin has a "bundled" number of 212.5712.43.

Maven plugin settings should be defaults, as below:
[image: maven plugin settings]

[image: compiler settings]

Anything else I can check to understand this behavior?  I know that `project.build.directory` is a maven identifier, but it does not appear in my `pom.xml` and in any case, maven appears to be working just fine.

Comment: Can you show the project which produces that? Or make an example project which shows that behaviour?

Comment: Where is the pom file in your project??? You have located a lot of classes in `classes/...`... Source code has to be located in `src/main/java/<packageName>` and unit tests in `src/test/java/<package>/*Test.java` etc. Your setup looks completely wrong...

Comment: okay well this is helpful data, if I put the pom into the example project, the behavior goes away.  but the behavior remains in my production project.  Shall I start adding stuff back in  to see where it fails?

Comment: Also you have located a lot of things in `${project.build.directory}` which is wrong... The pom.xml file describes what kind of dependencies you need and many things that can be handled by IDEA...

Comment: @kharmbaise the folder was auto-generated.  thanks for the suggestion to package an example, I discovered how to work around the problem. I will post a solution in case this comes for anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could not be reproduced after recreating the folder from time machine, from source control, and also by manually copying in the contents.  Git was unable to detect any difference between the problem folder and the restored folders, however, intelliJ's problem behavior continued with the original folder. Perhaps intellij uses some kind of hidden semaphore system that is not captured in source control.

Because I am trying to create a smooth experience for beginning users, I was not happy to not be able to find a root cause of the issue but alas IntelliJ is a black box and there is no way for me to see what is actually going on.  Per Git the problem folder and the recovered folder were identical.

Bottom line:

Simply copying the project folder using the finder did not resolve the issue. Copying the project folder content to a new project folder resolved the issue.

- copy the entire project folder using some method
- delete the original project folder
- create a new folder for the project
- copy the nested content of the copy into the new folder using some method